# JavaScript heap out of memory issue when upgrade to angular v9

Tags: angular, angular9

i upgrade my angular 8 project to angular 9 but when i run ng serve it gives me this error
JavaScript heap out of memory.i try ng serve --max-old-space-size=4096 and

"scripts": {
"build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
},
but nothing works

[image]

my angular version
Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 16.20.1
OS: win32 x64

```
Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.8.3
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
    
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.13",
    "@types/jspdf": "1.1.31",
    "ag-grid-angular": "20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "20.0.0",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "4.1.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "2.1.2",
    "angular2-qrcode": "2.0.1",
    "angular2-qrscanner": "1.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "cornerstone-core": "2.2.8",
    "cornerstone-math": "0.1.7",
    "cornerstone-tools": "2.4.0",
    "cornerstone-wado-image-loader": "2.2.3",
    "crossfilter": "^1.3.12",
    "dicom-parser": "1.8.3",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "jsbarcode": "3.11.0",
    "json-to-pivot-json": "^1.0.1",
    "jspdf": "1.4.1",
    "jsrsasign": "10.1.13",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.2.7",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-tab": "0.4.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "1.3.8",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.3.1",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "qz-tray": "2.1.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```